# Problema lógico Método de Ordenação BubbleSort

Tags: java, classificação

Estou fazendo ordenação de números a partir de um arquivo CSV. Eu importo os números e passo para um Array List e converto o `ArrayList<String>` para `ArrayList<Integer>`. Ocorre que estou tendo problema de lógica ao ordenar os números. Os números até se organizaram, mas o maior número está saindo na frente de todos, e só a partir do próximo número que inicia a ordem crescente, conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Método para passar os números do arquivo .CSV para o ArrayList:

```
public void PassVector()
{


    String LineFile = new String ();

    File fileCSV = new File(LocalFile.getText());

    try 

    {

        Numb = (ArrayList<String>) Files.lines(Paths.get(LocalFile.getText()))
        .flatMap(Pattern.compile(",")::splitAsStream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(Numb);



        Scanner reader = new Scanner(fileCSV);

        while (reader.hasNext())

        {

            LineFile = reader.nextLine();
            NumbLines+=1;

        }

        NumbNumbers = NumbLines * 2;

        //System.out.println(NumbLines);

        //ConvertArrayList(Numb);



    }           


    catch (IOException e)

    {
        System.out.println("Não foi possível carregar o vetor. \n\n Código do erro: " + e);
    }


}
```

Método para converter o `ArrayList <String>` para `ArrayList<Integer>`

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getIntegerArray(ArrayList<String> ArrayConvert) {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(String stringValue : ArrayConvert) {
        try {
            //Convert String to Integer, and store it into integer array list.
            result.add(Integer.parseInt(stringValue));
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
           //System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
            //Log.w("NumberFormat", "Parsing failed! " + stringValue + " can not be an integer");
        } 
    }       
    return result;
}
```

Método de Ordenação BubbleSort (Com erro lógico):

```
public static void Bubble(ArrayList<Integer> BubbleVector)

    {



        for (int i=0; i<BubbleVector.size();i=i+2)

        {

            for (int j=2; j<(BubbleVector.size()-1);j=j+2)

            {

                if (BubbleVector.get(i) < BubbleVector.get(j))

                {
                    Auxiliar1 = BubbleVector.get(i);
                    Auxiliar2 = BubbleVector.get(i+1);
                    BubbleVector.set(i, BubbleVector.get(j));
                    BubbleVector.set(i+1, BubbleVector.get(j+1));
                    BubbleVector.set(j, Auxiliar1);
                    BubbleVector.set(j+1, Auxiliar2);

                }

            }


        }

        System.out.println(BubbleVector);

    }
```

Arquivo CSV com números a serem ordenados

[image: Arquivo CSV com números a serem ordenados]

Comment: `Collections.sort(BubbleVector)` Simples assim.

Answer (score 3):

A lógica do [BubbleSort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) funciona comparando um valor X fixado pelo laço mais externo com todos os outros do array através do laço mais interno, e quando este valor X  for menor, é feita a troca de posição.

Nenhum dos seus laços segue essa lógica, o bubblesort varre de um a um. A lógica deste método seria a seguinte:

```
int size = lista.size();

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    for(int j = i; j < size; j++) {

      if(array.get(i) < array.get(j)){
       //troca
      }

    }
}
```

Lembrando que Classes derivadas de `Collections` podem ser ordenadas apenas com um simples `Collections.sort(lista)`

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86041/discussion-on-answer-by-articuno-l-problema-logico-metodo-de-ordenacao-bubblesor) - Se pretendem estender o assunto, usem o [link fornecido](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86041/discussion-on-answer-by-articuno-l-problema-logico-metodo-de-ordenacao-bubblesor).